# Manually edit MSIL in compiled DLL

Tags: .net, cil

If you want to make a small change to a .net application, is it possible to edit the MSIL directly?

Comment: Anything wrong with just dis-assembling and re-assembling?

Comment: This is more just out of interest than practical use

Comment: I recall a Reflector addin that allows this, but not sure if it still works. ReflexIL IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) to decompile and recompile with [ilasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx). For strong-named assemblies you will need the key file if you want that the recompiled assembly has the same identity as the original assembly.

Comment: Or use sn.exe to turn off Strong Name validation for that key.  If you're only interested in running the modified assembly on your machine.