# Prevent RegisterClassHandler callback from being executed

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a third party product where a view has a class handler for a routed event. The class handler contains unwanted code. Ideally, I would like to remove the call to [RegisterClassHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597874(v=vs.110).aspx) entirely, but unfortunately I don't have the source code. I have read that there is no way to unregister a class handler. Is there any other way to prevent the callback from being executed?

```
static ThirdPartyView
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
        typeof(ThirdPartyView),
        Control.PreviewLostKeyboardFocusEvent,
        new KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(OnPreviousLostKeyboardFocus),
        true);
}
```

### Prerequisites

- No, I cannot modify the source code.
- No, I cannot inherit the view class and override methods.
- No, I cannot intercept the creation of this view.
- No, I cannot alter bits in the strong-named assembly.

**How can I remove/disable/deactivate this class handler?**

Answer (score 0):

If a library you have is not a `netcore` library, then you can probably try using IL editors, something like this one https://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/ or https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy or http://reflexil.net/
When you find a `RegisterClassHandler` invocation I guess you can try replacing `new KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(OnPreviousLostKeyboardFocus)` with null. And if it doesn't work you might try erasing the whole method call.

If it's a `netcore` project you still can edit IL code, but I am not sure that tools that do that and has GUI are keeping up with new `netcore` versions released

Comment: Crazy idea :) Though, it will not work due to Strong-Naming.

Comment: @l33t It might be harder with a strong-named library. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746387/manually-edit-msil-in-compiled-dll
Editing IL code is not as hard as one might think

Comment: Another crazy idea is to use unsafe code to change memory block that has a delegate. I might try it and let you know how it goes

Comment: No sane ideas? :P